# Git command output is in editor (vim) and not directly to terminal output

Tags: git, vim

I don't know why but the output from some git command are in editor (vim) and not directly to the terminal output.

For example, the command `git branch` open vim and list the branches but I would like that the output are directly in the terminal.

I didn't set vim as default editor on the git config.

My config is Ubuntu 18.04 and zsh with oh-my-zsh plugin.

Comment: Git branch opens vim? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Can you post your `gitconfig` files? There will one in all of the following places: `/etc/gitconfig`, `~/.gitconfig`, and `.git/gitconfig` (this one is the `.git/` inside the repo directory)

Comment: Yes !!! 
Sorry the command open less and not vim. It is a default behavior change introduced in git 2.16

With `git --no-pager branch` or `git config --global pager.branch false` it's ok

Comment: This happened to me when I switched (suggested by macOS) my shell to zsh with no change to config.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Reply to myself.

It is a default behavior change introduced in git 2.16.

With `git --no-pager branch` or `git config --global pager.branch false` it's ok

Comment: Release notes here https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.16.0.txt#L85-L88

Comment: The latter: git config --global pager.branch false, worked for me.

Comment: ok, so I understand what it does, but does anybody know why they did this? it's really awful. Is there any use case where this is beneficial? When you have 100+ branches maybe?

Comment: This is awesome. It also works for logs: `git config --global pager.log false`