# VIM pager related problem with one Git repository

Tags: git

I am facing a problem with one particular Git repo in my local machine. I am using Windows 10. I do not have this problem with other repos. The problem occurs in both `pycharm` and in `cmd` and seems to be limited to `git branch` and `git log` commands.

When I run either of these commands I get the following error:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Press ENTER or type command to continueVim: Finished.
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

Vim: Finished.
```

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525244/git-command-output-is-in-editor-vim-and-not-directly-to-terminal-output) I realized that adding the `--no-pager` option allows me to circumvent this problem and output the desired result. I checked some items in `git config` related to pagers but nothing amounting to solving the problem.

Why does this occur, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Does setting your `TERM` environment variable to either `cygwin` or `msys` as [suggested in an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7950092/123109) silence the warnings?

Comment: Unset `git config core.pager` in the repository or set it to `less`.

Comment: Did you set your pager (locally, for this repository) to vim?

Comment: @phd I think I might have accidentally reset my pager to `vim`. When I do `git config  --local core.pager` I get `vim`. When I do `git config --global core.pager` I get nothing. How to I unset the local configuration variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @phd's comment I was able to find the problem. I ran `git config --local --edit` and found that `pager` was set to both `vim` and `notepad++`. I deleted both entries, such that no pager variable is defined at all in my local configuration file and reran `git branch` and it worked.